# Is there an IDE for java programming on a blackberry?

Tags: java, ide, blackberry

How can I do my java programming on a Blackberry? I am not looking for Blackberry app development. I am looking for a way to work on a java webapp project while not at my PC. Ideally, I would like to be able to connect to a server on my desktop, download some Java code from an existing project... edit it, and send it back to the server to compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right question to ask yourself would be more like 'Is there a Java SDK for Blackberry'. So far there is no such SDK by Sun and I don't think that there is any usable one.
I guess your best shot would be to try some remote desktop application for Blackberry, but then it would still be very inconvenient to use, because desktop UIs are not designed to be used on a handheld device.

Note: I know that Eclipse features its own compiler and could be used for simple tasks running only on JRE, but it is more of an exception than the rule when it comes to java IDEs.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know of any java sdk for the blackberry platform, yet. But there is one for android platform developed by Hans Kratz and his team. http://echo.com.ng/2013/programming-with-your-smartphone/